# Memory usage keeps increasing with 'identity_map_enabled' in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I run a Rails app with Mongoid database backend on a server with 1 GB RAM.
The database itself sits on a different db server.

Whenever I run a rake task that iterates over some collections, I notice that the RAM usage keeps increasing in **htop** until the server becomes unresponsive.

This only happens when the value:

`identity_map_enabled: true` is set in the mongoid.yml config file.

I'm using 
**Mongoid gem 2.4.11**.
I know it's an old version the most recent being 4.0.

Considering a systemwide ORM update is not feasible, is there any way I can patch up existing code to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doc explictly states to disable identity map in rake tasks etc.

I created this:

```
class MongoidUtils
  def self.without_identity_map &block
    if Mongoid.identity_map_enabled
      Mongoid.identity_map_enabled = false
      result = yield
      Mongoid.identity_map_enabled = true
      result
    else
      yield
    end
  end
end
```

Then use it this way:

```
MongoidUtils.without_identity_map do
  #your code here
end
```

Comment: Ah pretty shameful that I missed the documentation about it. Many thanks for the answer though!